# Reloading a Stimulsoft report from a string is missing the original table data

Tags: stimulsoft

I saved a Stimulsoft report (containing some variables and a table) to a string using this method:

```
string s = report1.savetostring();
```

When I reload this report in other Stimulsoft report, all data in the second report comes except the table data:

```
report2.loadfromstring(s);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean under table data? If it is data sources then the data in not sored in the report template and you should register it again.

Comment: I want to save this report as string in database and then in other part of program when user asks, restore report from database and in this time there is no table to register it.in this case all data is restored except that table contents.

Comment: No Data is stored in the report temaplte.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is use the `SaveDocumentToString` method instead.  Be sure to render the report first.

```
report1.Render();
string s = report1.SaveDocumentToString();
```

Then to load the report (with data)

```
report2.LoadDocumentFromString(s);
```